# PODS performance vs custom field

Tags: custom-field, performance, pods-framework

is using pods's own content tpye where custom fields are all stored in one table more scalable than custom fields of wordpress where each field is a row in the meta table...

I haven't used PODS yet but storing all fields in one table seems more scalable and easier to maintain?

what are the disadvantages of PODS (i don't see many people using it)? are the custom fields of pods indexable for the search engine?

Comment: Your question is essentially "is one table better than one table" in current form?..

Answer (score 5):

Pods allows you to create meta-based or table-based content types. Meta-based work as normal WP post types do. You can also extend WP objects like Comments, Users, Media, and Taxonomies to add custom fields to those.

If you choose to use table-based Pods, it creates a table with the ID field and only the custom fields that you define yourself. There are benefits that can be had by this, for cases where there's a lot of data that needs to be specifically queried and filtered against, where otherwise postmeta may be constricting based on hosting budgets or if you need to query against specific values often. Custom indexes can then be added by hand to any of the Pods tables which further improve performance based on the types of queries you prefer.

Table-based Pods have a few caveats, mainly being there is no WP_Query support for meta_query (yet, it's in progress), and when you use the default WP search, it won't search those fields' content. That doesn't stop you from being able to do things with it, like using the Pods API calls like http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/find/ which is pretty powerful on it's own. In many ways, it can be invaluable for complex queries and filtering, when compared to WP_Query.

Here's a couple more comparisons between how table-based Pods compare against the normal WP default meta-based content types:

- http://pods.io/docs/comparisons/compare-content-types/
- http://pods.io/docs/comparisons/compare-storage-types/
- http://pods.io/docs/comparisons/compare-wp_query-wp__query-and-pods-unified-theming/

Comment: is there a way to add the fields in the seperate pod table to the search of wp or even better to relevansi plugin? Which seems to be the best search plugin for wp

Comment: Not yet, we're looking at all sorts of ideas for integration of table-based content with existing solutions. Currently the top contender is SearchWP support.

Comment: ah ok but searchWP is not free :( ... will look at relevanssi code ... it should be a too much of a problem adding fields from the seperate tables to the post's search indexes

Comment: I have a question(where can i post questions for PODS?), is it possible to migrate and existing post type with meta fields to a seperate table later on or do i need to set up the seperate table right from the start?

Comment: [You must disclose your affiliation in your answers.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: @toscho I didn't think I needed to explain I'm the lead developer of Pods, since the question was about Pods, but I'll do that in the future.

Comment: @yeahman It's possible, we're working on a number of migration scripts that lets you change a Post Type into a Taxonomy, User, or Advanced Content Type (or between any of those). Also one for migrating between table vs meta.

Comment: do update_post_meta or get_post_meta work if i choose table storage for meta fields?

Comment: Actually, yes they do work, we built in support for those.

Comment: But get_post_meta() only seems to work for one key - you can't leave the key parameter empty to retrieve all fields for a post.